# A 'child' property of a custom Widget (BuildSectionContainer) is not rendering at all, when I am trying to implement it in another Widget (HomeBody)

Tags: flutter, dart

**1. This is my custom widget to build a container section with a child property.**

```
class BuildSectionContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  const BuildSectionContainer({
    required this.healthService,
    required this.service,
    this.sectionTitle,
    this.child,
  });

  final HealthServices healthService;
  final List<HealthService> service;
  final String? sectionTitle;
  // =========================
  final Widget? child;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(
          width: 2,
          color: Colors.black12,
        ),
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          /// SECTION TITLE
          Center(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text(
                '$sectionTitle',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

**2. Here I tried to use the 'child' property, but nothing is getting rendered. I suspected unbound height/width, but even after applying the value of height/width can't get anything.**

**3. Can anyone help me with what is going wrong here? Thanks in advance for your help.**

```
class HomeBody extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final healthService = Provider.of<HealthServices>(context);
    final service = healthService.services;

    return Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor.withOpacity(0.1),
      //
      child: ListView(
        physics: ScrollPhysics(),
        shrinkWrap: true,
        children: [
          // ==========================================
          BuildSectionContainer(
            healthService: healthService,
            service: service,
            sectionTitle: 'SERVICES',
            child: Container(
              height: 245,
              width: 245,
              color: Colors.blue,

              **// child property implented here**
              child: Text('GRID VIEW'),
              // ============================
            ),
          )
          // ===================================================
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

**4. Model file**

```
class HealthService with ChangeNotifier {
  Icon icon;
  String serviceName;

  HealthService({required this.icon, required this.serviceName});
}

class HealthServices with ChangeNotifier {
  List<HealthService> _services = [
    HealthService(
      icon: Icon(Icons.mic),
      serviceName: 'Audio Consultation',
    ),
    HealthService(
      icon: Icon(Icons.video_call_outlined),
      serviceName: 'Video Consultation',
    ),
    HealthService(
      icon: Icon(Icons.chat_bubble_outline),
      serviceName: 'Chat Consultation',
    ),
    HealthService(
      icon: Icon(Icons.schedule_outlined),
      serviceName: 'Book Appointment',
    ),        
  ];

  List<HealthService> get services {
    return [..._services];
  }
}
```

Comment: Where you used the child ? I can't see that in your code

Comment: can u share data_model code too ''HealthServices"

Comment: The child property is used in the last line of the HomeBody.

Comment: hey Rajat, added the model file

Comment: @NikashDeka Where did you used that in `BuildSectionContainer` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are not using the passed `child` property anywhere. Modify your `BuildSectionContainer` to something like:

```dart
class BuildSectionContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  const BuildSectionContainer({
    required this.healthService,
    required this.service,
    this.sectionTitle,
    this.child,
  });

  final HealthServices healthService;
  final List<HealthService> service;
  final String? sectionTitle;
  final Widget? child;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(
          width: 2,
          color: Colors.black12,
        ),
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Center(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text(
                '$sectionTitle',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          // Using child here
          // Can also write if(child != null)...[child!] else ...[Container(),],
          child?? Container(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you help with the issue of the ListView scroll effect?

Comment: @NikashDeka Could you please add it as a separate question? Your current edit makes the actual answer irrelevant. Please add the newly posted question link, I'll try to answer.